# Google test compilation error Os X : ambiguous conversion for functional-style cast from 'int' to 'internal::FloatingEq2Matcher<float>'

Tags: c++, googletest

I get this error when compiling my tests on Mac Os. Please could you help me find a proper solution

This is how I installed googletest:

```
cd ~/  
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git
cd googletest 
mkdir install 
cd install 
cmake ../  #creates a make file 
make #compiles Google Test
sudo make install #installs Google Test
echo "export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib" >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

And the compilation output:

```
g++ Arduino_unittest.cc -std=c++11 -lgtest -lgtest_main -lgmock -pthread -I ../include
In file included from Arduino_unittest.cc:5:
In file included from ../include/arduino-mock/Arduino.h:74:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock.h:61:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:39:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:47:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:75:
/usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3976:10: error: ambiguous conversion for functional-style cast from 'int'
      to 'internal::FloatingEq2Matcher<float>'
  return internal::FloatingEq2Matcher<float>(true);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1535:12: note: candidate constructor
  explicit FloatingEq2Matcher(bool nan_eq_nan) { Init(-1, nan_eq_nan); }
           ^
/usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1537:12: note: candidate constructor
  explicit FloatingEq2Matcher(FloatType max_abs_error) {
           ^
/usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3982:10: error: ambiguous conversion for functional-style cast from 'int'
      to 'internal::FloatingEq2Matcher<double>'
  return internal::FloatingEq2Matcher<double>(true);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1535:12: note: candidate constructor
  explicit FloatingEq2Matcher(bool nan_eq_nan) { Init(-1, nan_eq_nan); }
           ^
/usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1537:12: note: candidate constructor
  explicit FloatingEq2Matcher(FloatType max_abs_error) {
           ^
2 errors generated.
```

Output of c++ --version

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: It may help if you post the error producing code of `Arduino_unittest.cc`.

Comment: The errors come from gmock-matchers.h . Here is the file and the googletest repo:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone happens to hit this issue, this is unrelated to gmock. That error is caused by some header you might be including on MacOS **that redefines true to 1**. In my case, the redefinition was being done by ldns system header.

In order to find out where exactly `true` is being defined to `1`, add a redefinition of `true` to the top of the file in your project where the error is being triggered. Something like:

```cpp
#define true true
```

This has to be done before all includes, and you will get a build error showing where the redefinition is taking place.